# BufferedImage doesn't draw from 0,0

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe, paint

I hope my first post isn't too basic for y'all.

I'm trying to do some per-pixel drawing on a JCanvas using a BufferedImage (using setRGB()). I thought I would test all was working with a single diagonal line from the origin to the width/height of the JCanvas. The trouble is that I get a strange offset in the x axis that I can't seem to fix!

Here's a link to the problem:
http://i811.photobucket.com/albums/zz31/bohngy/problemMandel_zpsae20713a.jpeg

[image]

Here's the code:

```
public class Mandelbrot extends JFrame {

private BufferedImage I;

public Mandelbrot() {
    super("Mandelbrot Set");
    setSize(600, 600);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    I = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int x = 0; x < getHeight(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < getWidth(); y++) {
            I.setRGB(x, x, Color.GREEN.getRGB());
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(I, 0, 0, this);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Mandelbrot().setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: This line makes me a little nervous: `I.setRGB(x, x, Color.GREEN.getRGB());` with the use of `x` twice as a parameter

Answer (score 3):

General issues

- Don't extend `JFrame` (particularly, don't override the `paint` method of `JFrame`). Instead, do the painting in the `paintComponent` method a class that extends `JPanel`
- Create the GUI from the Event Dispatch Thread

The main reason for the unexpected result is that you are creating an image that has the size of the frame - but the frame also has a title bar and a border, and these are "covering" parts of the image. The size of the area that is actually available for painting is smaller than the total frame size. Additionally, the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods *may* return garbage as long as the frame is not yet visible on the screen.

One approach considering all this could look like in this snippet:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Mandelbrot 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));

        BufferedImage image = createImage(500, 500);
        ImagePanel imagePanel = new ImagePanel(image);
        frame.getContentPane().add(imagePanel);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static BufferedImage createImage(int w, int h)
    {
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(w, h,
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
        {
            image.setRGB(x, x, Color.GREEN.getRGB());
        }
        return image;
    }

    static class ImagePanel extends JPanel
    {
        private final BufferedImage image;

        ImagePanel(BufferedImage image)
        {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize()
        {
            if (super.isPreferredSizeSet())
            {
                return super.getPreferredSize();
            }
            return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
        {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: While I'll except your answer as been relatively correct, you could also achieve the same thing by using a JLabel instead of the ImagePanel, just saying +1

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Originally, he also was painting the image manually, and the ImagePanel shows how this can be done in a `JPanel#paintComponent`. But of course, if it's just about *somehow displaying* the image, an `...add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image)));` would do it, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

All BufferedImage objects have an upper left corner coordinate of (0, 0). Any Raster used to construct a BufferedImage must therefore have minX=0 and minY=0.

Therein lies your problem.

JavaDoc for [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)

Edit:

Also remove this from your loop:

```
for (int y = 0; y < getWidth(); y++) {
    I.setRGB(x, x, Color.GREEN.getRGB());
}
```